# Inner/Dot List Vector (Looks like `MatrixPower` but in fact not the same)

Tags: expression-manipulation

(This question comes from the last input of [Converting Equations to Sparse Arrays](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LinearAlgebraSparseArrays#139087150) in Wolfram Documentation.)

I want to get this (by extensible code):

```
s0 + s1.{x,y} + s2.{x,y}.{x,y} + s3.{x,y}.{x,y}.{x,y}
```

But this is my failed trial:

In:

```
Symbol["s" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[0, 3]

(*Focus below:*)

NestList[HoldForm@Dot[#, {x, y}] &, {x, y}, 2]~Prepend~1
Inner[Times, %%, %, Plus]~Collect~{x, y}
```

Out:

```
{s0, s1, s2, s3}
{1,{x,y},{x,y}.{x,y},({x,y}.{x,y}).{x,y}}
{s0+s1 x+s3 ({x,y}.{x,y}).{x,y}+s2 {x,y}.{x,y},s0+s1 y+
s3 ({x,y}.{x,y}).{x,y}+s2 {x,y}.{x,y}}
```

---

## Q&A

(Q by me, A by @J.M.)

1. The parentheses are redundant, can them be dropped?
   [image: parentheses]

> Without the parentheses, ***Mathematica*** tries to be smart and **automagically** evaluates `{x, y}.{x, y}` to `x^2 + y^2`, which surely is not what you wanted.

2. I don't know how to apply `MatrixPower` to achieve that, since the documentation says "`MatrixPower` works only on square matrices". Is `MatrixPower` impracticable?

> `MatrixPower[]` is useful, but this is not a case where it is so.

---

Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Fold[]` + `Distribute[]`:

```
Fold[Distribute[Inactive[Dot][#, {x, y}]] + #2 &, {s3, s2, s1, s0}]
   s0 + s1.{x, y} + (s2.{x, y}).{x, y} + ((s3.{x, y}).{x, y}).{x, y}
```

where I had suppressed the inactivated dot products for readability; evaluating this in *Mathematica* should yield the desired inactive form.

Comment: 2 bit more: 1. Can you drop redundant parentheses? \\ 2. Is `MatrixPower` impracticable?

Comment: 1. Without the parentheses, *Mathematica* tries to be smart and automagically evaluates `{x, y} . {x, y}` to `x^2 + y^2`, which surely is not what you wanted. 2. `MatrixPower[]` is useful, but this is not a case where it is so.

Answer (score 4):

```
symbols = Symbol["s" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[0, 3];
xy = NestList[Inactive[Dot][#, {x, y}] &, {x, y}, 2]~Prepend~1;

Inner[Inactive[Dot], symbols, xy]
```

> [image]